# Rotate table data with out update data

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-server-2000, limit

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

->This will display the first 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

->This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

I want to Show data 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1 and
next day 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2 
day after next day 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3

IS IT POSSIBLE with out updating any data of this table ???

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5 UNION SELECT * FROM `your_table`
```

This will first select rows within your limit, and then combine the remainder from the second select. Note that you don't need to set a limit on the second select statement:

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Comment: Thank you Andrew it is wokring now perfect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this might be achieved using a simple Select (I may be wrong). I think you'll need a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this as Oracle, though your SQL syntax would be invalid for Oracle because it doesn't support LIMIT

However, here's a solution that will work in Oracle:

```
select *
  from ( select rownum as rn,
                user_id
           from admin_user
          order by user_id
       ) X
 where X.rn > :startRows
   and X.rn <= :startRows + :limitRows
 order by case when X.rn <= :baseRef
                    then X.rn + :limitRows
               else
                    X.rn
          end ASC
;
```

where :startRows and :limitRows are the values for your LIMIT, and :baseRef is a value between 0 and :limitRows-1 that should be incremented/cycled on a daily basis (ie on day 1 it should be 0; on day 2, 1; on day 10, 9; on day 11 you should revert to 0). You could actually use the current date, converted to Julian and take the remainder when divided by :limitRows to automate calculating :baseRef

(substitute your own column and table names as appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be a little bit late for the author of the question, but could be useful for people.

**Short answer**: It is possible to do the "spin" like author asked.

**Long answer**: [I'm going to explain for MySQL first - where I tested this]

Let's imagine that we have table **your_table** (INT rn, ...). What you want is to sort in specific way ("spin" with beginning at the rn=N). First condition of ordering is rn >= N desc. The idea (at least how I understand this) is we change the order from **asc** to **desc** and split our table in two parts (<N and >=N). Then we order this back by rn but **asc** order. It will execute sorting for each group independently. So here is our query:

```
select * from your_table where rn between 1 and 10
order by rn >= N desc, rn asc;
```

If you don't have rn column - you always can use the trick with parameter

```
select t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn 
from your_table t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
where @rownum < 10 /* here be careful - we already increased by 1 the rownum */
order by @rownum >=N - 1 desc, /* another tricky place (cause we already increased rownum) */
         @rownum asc;
```

I don't know if the last one is efficient, though.

For Oracle, you always can use [rownum](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html). And I believe that you will have the same result (I didn't test it!).

Hope it helps!